# AST selector for eslint rule for Angular ngOnChanges method

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint, abstract-syntax-tree

The idea is to validate ngOnChanges Angular method.

- it should have `changes` of type `SimpleChanges` as an argument
- inside the function when accessing the property `currentChanges` should be optionaly chained

so an example of invalid code is

```
public ngOnChanges(notChangesName: NotSimpleShanges) {
  notChangesName.property.currentValue;
}
```

an example of valid code is

```
public ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleShanges) {
  changes.property?.currentValue;
}
```

The best I came with is

```
"no-restricted-syntax": [
  "error",
  {
    "message": "Changes currentValue should be optionally chained",
    "selector": "MemberExpression[optional=false] > Identifier[name=\"currentValue\"]"
  },
  {
    "message": "ngOnChanges should have 'changes' as an argument of type 'SimpleChanges'",
    "selector": "MethodDefinition[key.name=\"ngOnChanges\"] > FunctionExpression > Identifier[name!=\"changes\"]"
  },
  {
    "message": "ngOnChanges should have 'changes' as an argument of type 'SimpleChanges'",
    "selector": "MethodDefinition[key.name=\"ngOnChanges\"] > FunctionExpression > BlockStatement:not(:has(Parameter))"
  }
]
```

The problems are:

1. Selector `MemberExpression[optional=false] > Identifier[name=\"currentValue\"]` checks `currentValue` is optionaly chained to any variable. I need it to be checked if the parent has name `changes` (`changes.field.currentValue`)
2. Type of `changes` is not checked by selector
   `MethodDefinition[key.name=\"ngOnChanges\"] > FunctionExpression > Identifier[name!=\"changes\"]`. It should be of type `SimpleChanges`

UPD: Current solution is:

```
"no-restricted-syntax": [
  "error",
  {
    "message": "Properties 'currentValue | firstChange | previousValue | isFirstChange' should be optional",
    "selector": "MethodDefinition[key.name='ngOnChanges'] MemberExpression[object.object.name='changes'][optional=false][property.name=/.*/]"
  },
  {
    "message": "ngOnChanges should have 'changes' as an argument",
    "selector": "MethodDefinition[key.name='ngOnChanges'] > FunctionExpression > Identifier[name!='changes']"
  },
  {
    "message": "ngOnChanges should have 'changes: NgChanges' as an argument",
    "selector": "MethodDefinition[key.name='ngOnChanges'] > FunctionExpression > Identifier >  TSTypeAnnotation > TSTypeReference > Identifier[name!='SimpleChanges']"
  },
  {
    "message": "ngOnChanges should have one argument 'changes: NgChanges'",
    "selector": "MethodDefinition[key.name='ngOnChanges'] > FunctionExpression[params.length!=1]"
  }
]
```

Comment: For the first problem solution can be:
`MethodDefinition[key.name=\"ngOnChanges\"] MemberExpression[object.object.name='changes'][optional=false][property.name=/.*/]`

but it highlights `changes`. Not `currentValue` in `changes.field.currentValue`
not a big problem though

Comment: And for the second problem selector `MethodDefinition[key.name='ngOnChanges'] > FunctionExpression > Identifier >  TSTypeAnnotation > TSTypeReference > Identifier[name!='SimpleChanges']` will do for now